# java - Is invoking super constructor in derived constructor same with set field value exactly?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

There are two ways to define constructor of Derived class in java.

In `DerivedClassWithSuper`, I use `super()` function to define constructor.
But, in `DerivedClassWithoutSuper` I don't use `super()` function to define constructor.

One thing I want to know is that there are any difference between them?

I also know that `DerivedClassWithSuper` looks better code, but I'm not sure if there are any side effects when I define constructor like in `DerivedClassWithoutSuper`

```java
class BaseClass {
    int id;
    BaseClass () {
        this.id = 0;
        System.out.printf("Base class is created, id: %d \n", this.id);
    }
}

class DerivedClassWithSuper extends BaseClass {
    String name;
    DerivedClassWithSuper () {
        super(); 
        // this.id = 0;
        this.name = "Unknown";
        System.out.printf("DerivedClassWithSuper is created, this.id: %d, name: %s\n", this.id, this.name);
    }
}

class DerivedClassWithoutSuper extends BaseClass {
    String name;
    DerivedClassWithoutSuper () {
        this.id = 0;
        this.name = "Unknown";
        System.out.printf("DerivedClassWithoutSuper is created, id: %d, name: %s\n", this.id, this.name);
    }
}
```

I always thanks for all your help. Thanks.

---

**Additional Questions:**
if there are not `super()` function, derived class call `super()` implicilty.

In the below code which is a little changed, In `DerivedClassWithoutSuper` constructor set `this.id` as 10, and it call `super()` function implicitly. if `super()` called, `this.id` or `super.id` should be set as 0.

But, `super.id` and `this.id` are 10.

I can't understand why this happen.

```java
class BaseClass {
    int id;
    BaseClass () {
        this.id = 0;
        System.out.printf("Base class is created, id: %d \n", this.id);
    }
}

class DerivedClassWithSuper extends BaseClass {
    String name;
    DerivedClassWithSuper () {
        super();
        this.name = "Unknown";
        System.out.printf("DerivedClassWithSuper is created");
        System.out.printf("%d %d\n", this.id, super.id);
    }
}

class DerivedClassWithoutSuper extends BaseClass {
    String name;
    DerivedClassWithoutSuper () {
        // if super() implicitly called?
        this.id = 10;
        this.name = "Unknown";
        System.out.printf("DerivedClassWithoutSuper is created\n");
        // then this.id and super.id should be different. 
        // but, both are 10 as set in this constructor. 
        System.out.printf("%d %d\n", this.id, super.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: `super()` does not 'define constructor'. It *invokes* the *parent* constructor. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: 1) `this.id = 0;` is redundant, since numeric fields are 0 by default. --- 2) Yes, `super()` is called implicitly at beginning of constructor, if no explicit call is made. --- 3) `id`, `this.id` and `super.id` **all** refer to the one and only `id` field of `BaseClass`. --- 4) Why wouldn't `id` be `10` after you assigned it that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a subclass constructor doesn't call `super(...)` (or `this(...)`) explicitly, the compiler will implicitly call the no-arg `super()` constructor for you. If no such constructor exists, compilation will fail, even though you never wrote the call.

See e.g. [The Java™ Tutorials - Using the Keyword super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html):

> **Note:** If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. `Object` *does* have such a constructor, so if `Object` is the only superclass, there is no problem.

Comment: `super(...) (or this(...))` ? `this(...)` is not the same as `super(...)`! Even if you have `this(...)` you will get error!

Comment: @tashkhisi I never said that `this(...)` is the same as `super(...)`, but all constructors *(except the `Object()` constructor)* **must** call another constructor, explicitly or implicitly. You can call `this(...)` *or* you can call `super(...)` *or* you can leave it to the compiler to call `super()` implicitly.

Comment: I got what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I add additional question. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @frhyme Don't add more questions to a question. Only one question per question, so create a new question.